# How do get the working directory after a cd in a makefile?

Tags: bash, macos, makefile, gnu-make, pwd

I just need to be able to assign the value of `pwd` after `cd` to a variable so I can open a file in my web browser, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that in a Makefile. Interestingly, when searching other answers about people who want to get the directory of the currently-running Makefile after a cd (as opposed to what I want to do, which is get the actual current working directory regardless of where the Makefile is), doing things that they said don't work after a cd still seem to point to the Makefile, not the directory I cd'd into.

I'm running GNU Make 3.81 on Mac OS 10.15, if that matters.

This is my directory setup:

```
whatever/
|
├── foo/
│    ├── Makefile
│    └── make_a_file.py
└── bar/
     └── Makefile
```

make_a_file.py generates output.txt. make_a_file.py can be run from /foo/Makefile via `make bizz`, resulting in:

```
whatever/
|
├── foo/
│    ├── Makefile
│    ├── make_a_file.py
│    └── output.txt
└── bar/
     └── Makefile
```

If I manually copy output.txt to the bar directory, and run /bar/Makefile's `make html`, I end up with an html file in bar, i.e.,

```
whatever/
|
├── foo/
│    ├── Makefile
│    ├── make_a_file.py
│    └── output.txt
└── bar/
     ├── Makefile
     ├── output.txt
     └── output.html
```

My problem is that I want to open output.html in my web browser using /foo/Makefile, but it seems that I cannot get the **absolute** path of /bar/output.html, so I can't call something like `python -mwebbrowser file:///$(WHATEVER)/bar/output.html` or `python -mwebbrowser file:///$(FULLPATH)/output.html`. I do not want to hardcode the absolute path; I can only count on bar/ and foo/ not changing their names, not necessarily anything above them.

This is what /foo/Makefile currently looks like.

```
bizz:
    python make_a_file.py

compile:
    cp outputs/outfile.txt ../bar/output.txt
    cd ../bar/; \
    echo "$(PWD)"; \
    echo "$(shell pwd)"; \
    echo "$(CURDIR)"; \
    make html; \
    python -mwebbrowser file:///$(CURDIR)/_build/html/output.html
```

Which results this when I run it from foo/:

```
(venv) foo user$ make compile
cp output.txt ../bar/output.txt
cd ../bar/; \
    echo "/whatever/foo"; \
    echo "/whatever/foo"; \
    echo "/whatever/foo"; \
    make html; \
    python -mwebbrowser file:////whatever/foo/output.html
/whatever/foo
/whatever/foo
/whatever/foo
Running Sphinx v4.4.0
[and other miscellaneous output from the makefile in bar]
build succeeded.

0:85: execution error: File some object wasn’t found. (-43)
```

I know that the cd must have worked, and that the `make html` must be executed in the same subshell as the cd because `make html` does not work without cd'ing into bar first. And yet, all of the echos would you have believe that you are still in foo.

What's going on here? Is there a way around this without hardcoding the absolute path?

Comment: I don't know about the python module you're using, but many web browsers will accept a relative (or absolute) path on the command line in place of a URI.  If yours does, then that would moot the whole issue.

Comment: Alternatively, you have discovered several ways to obtain `make`'s initial working directory, and right there in the recipe you have a path relative to that.  You can easily build an absolute path directly from those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods you've tried are all evaluated by `make` before the shell command is ever executed. You need to write a shell command that outputs the current directory, one that executes after the `cd`.

The simplest option is `pwd`:

```
compile:
    cp outputs/outfile.txt ../bar/output.txt
    cd ../bar/; \
    pwd; \
    make html; \
    python -mwebbrowser file:///$$(pwd)/_build/html/output.html
```

Alternatively, you could delay the evaluation of `$PWD` by escaping the `$` so that the shell evaluates it rather than `make`:

```
compile:
    cp outputs/outfile.txt ../bar/output.txt
    cd ../bar/; \
    echo $$PWD; \
    make html; \
    python -mwebbrowser file:///$$PWD/_build/html/output.html
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you so much. Is there a way to know if a variable/command will be set before or during shell execution? The Gnu make quick reference for CURDIR doesn't say when it is set, and it doesn't mention pwd at all.